# GET request: how to send query?

Tags: get, dart

I would like to know what is the correct procedure for making a GET request inside the application code. I mean, not in the URL (is that a good practice?).

As always, I like to give you examples on what I'm looking for. So here it is:

HTML:

```
(...)
    <div class="input-area">
        <input type="text" value="SOME VALUE" id="text-field">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="button">
    </div>
(...)
```

Let's assume that the #button action is "submitForm".

DART (it's incomplete):

```
void submitForm(Event e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    request = new HttpRequest();
    request.onReadyStateChange.listen(dataIsReady);
    request.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:8123");
    (???)
}
```

What I would like to happen is the value on the text-field to be sent to the server as a parameter. Just to clarify, I'll be using that parameter to search for some entries in a MySQL database (and return some JSON data).

So how can I do that with Dart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dart
library x;

import 'dart:html';

void main() {

// you can create an URI and use the toString() method to create a 
// String you can pass to the request

  Map query = {
    'xx': 'yy',
    'zz': 'ss'
  };
  Uri uri =
      new Uri(
          path: "http://localhost:8080/myapp/signinService",
          queryParameters: query);
  print('URI: ${uri.toString()}');


  querySelector("#signinForm")..onSubmit.listen(handle);
}

void handle(Event event) {
  event.preventDefault();

// or you can use the form elements formdata

  FormElement formElement = event.target as FormElement;

  var url = "http://localhost:8080/myapp/signinService";

  HttpRequest.request(
      url,
      method: formElement.method,
      sendData: new FormData(formElement)).then(onDataLoaded);
}


void onDataLoaded(HttpRequest req) {
  String response = req.responseText;
  if (response == 1) {
    window.alert("You are signed in!");
  } else {
    window.alert("Sign in failed. Check credentials.");
  }
}
```

html

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Alarm</h1>

<!-- I used a form element and set the request method here. It can be set in code too -->

    <form id="signinForm" class="form-signin" method="GET">
      <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
      <input type="text" class="input-block-level" name="email" placeholder="Email address">
      <input type="password" class="input-block-level" name="password" placeholder="Password">
      <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" id="signinBtn" type="submit">Sign in</button>
    </form>
    <script type="application/dart" src="alarm.dart"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Günter, in my example, "request.onReadyStateChange.listen(dataIsReady);" was responsible for setting the method that would handle the response from the server. But with "HttpRequest.getString" I can't set that. So I have to use ".then" to replace that "dataIsReady" handler, right?

Comment: io (file/network/...) operations are normally async. You need to chain subsequent operations with then.